# Usage of different headings with fancyhdr in a thesis

Tags: fancyhdr

I have been trying to insert different headings to my thesis.

The requirement is to show the frontmatter with Roman letters and the name of the section or chapter. The heading of the main part shall show the number of the chapter, the chapter title and the page number. The backmatter again shall show the same as the main part, thus the number of the chapter, title and page number. Sounds pretty easy. However, I have my difficulties.

I have tried the following code. It works fine for the frontmatter. The main and backmatter do not show the expected result. In the main matter, the number of the chapter is not shown and on the "rightmark" page, the section is shown instead of the chapter details.

Same for the backmatter. It shows the title twice in the header, but not the chapter number or the page number.

Attached you will find the equivalent code.

```latex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
     \markboth{\thechapter{} #1}{\thechapter{}#1}}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}
}
\fancypagestyle{back}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{\thechapter{} #1}{\thechapter{}#1}}
}
\appto\frontmatter{\pagestyle{plain}}
\appto\mainmatter{\pagestyle{main}}
\appto\backmatter{\pagestyle{back}}



%**Another way of doing it is the following:** 
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures={TeX, Common}]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=0.8]{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%

    \markboth{#1}{#1}}
}
%\fancypagestyle{main}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ 
    \markboth{\thechapter{} #1} {} }

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark} }
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark} 
}

\graphicspath{images/}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[style=alphabetic]{references.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{acronym}

\parindent0cm
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\makeatletter 
% Define frontmatter, mainmatter and backmatter if not defined 
\@ifundefined{frontmatter}{% 
    \newcommand{\frontmatter}{% 
       %In Roemischen Buchstaben nummerieren (i, ii, iii) 
       \pagenumbering{roman} 
    } 
}{} 
\@ifundefined{mainmatter}{% 
    % scrpage2 benoetigt den folgenden switch 
    % wenn \mainmatter definiert ist. 
%    \newif\if@mainmatter\@mainmattertrue 
    \newcommand{\mainmatter}{% 
       % -- Seitennummerierung auf Arabische Zahlen zuruecksetzen (1,2,3) 
       \pagenumbering{arabic}% 
       \setcounter{page}{1}% 
    } 
}{} 
\@ifundefined{backmatter}{% 
%    \newif\if@backmatter\@backmattertrue 
    \newcommand{\backmatter}{ %
       %In Roemischen Buchstaben nummerieren (i, ii, iii) 
       \pagenumbering{roman} 
    } 
}{} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
{\sffamily
%\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{2cm}

\begin{Huge}
{xx}
\end{Huge}
       
       \vspace{0.5cm}
        {\Large xx}
            
       \vspace{1cm}
\textbf{xx}\\
        \vspace{1cm}
zxx 

        \vspace{1cm}
\textbf{xx}

        \vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{(xx)}
        
\vspace{1cm}
          
                             
       von xx\\
       \vspace{0.5cm}
xx \\
        \vspace{0.5cm}
xx\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}
xx\\
        \vspace{1.5cm}
xx: \\
        \vspace{0.5cm}
xx\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}
xx\\
        \vspace{1cm}
xx     
%       \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{university}
           
            
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter 
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Vorwort}
\chapter{Danksagung}
xx
\chapter{Abstrakt}
xx
\chapter{Abstract}
xx
\chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[SEPSEP]
\acro{abb}[Abb.]{Abbildung}
\end{acronym}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Einleitung}
xx

\chapter{ssssssssss}
xx

\chapter{eeeeeeeeee}
cccc

\backmatter

\appendix
\chapter{Anhang}
ffffffffff
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I take it this is the \appto from etoolkit?

Comment: Hi John. Yes, this is the case. BR Ralph

Comment: You need to replace #1 with ##1.   Since \chaptermark is defined inside another macro, #1 refers to the (nonexistent) argument for `\ps@plain` (for example), and ##1 refers to the argument for \chaptermark.

Comment: Is this a crosspost to [Formatierung unterschiedliche Kopfzeile - es fehlt noch was](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=23193)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapters in backmatter are unnumbered. So, I think they should be unnumbered in the page header, too. Therefore I would use `\if@mainmatter` in a global redefinition of `\chaptermark`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter\thechapter{}\ \fi#1}{}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}% before the redefinition of \chaptermark

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter\thechapter{}\ \fi#1}{}}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{lipsum}% nur für Fülltext
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \Huge Titelseite\par
  \normalsize
  Weiterer Text auf der Titelseite
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter 
\chapter{Vorwort}
  \lipsum[1]
\chapter{Danksagung}
  \lipsum[2]
\chapter{Abstrakt}
  \lipsum[3]
\chapter{Abstract}
  \lipsum
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter

\chapter{Einleitung}
\lipsum
\chapter{ssssssssss}
\lipsum
\chapter{eeeeeeeeee}
\lipsum
\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Anhang}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note, that first page of each chapter uses pagestyle `plain`. If they should get the same layout, define fancypagestyle `plain` in the preamble:

```latex
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
}
```

or

```latex
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}% change plain pagestyle to fancy
```

Comment: Dear esdd. I have directy tried it and your code example works in the document! That is awesome! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ Ralph It the answer  solves your issue, you can upvote and maybe accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to create an MWE anyway, here it is.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
%\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}
\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\thechapter{} ##1}{\thechapter{}##1}}%
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{##1}{##1}}
}
\fancypagestyle{back}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{\thechapter{} ##1}{\thechapter{}##1}}
}
\appto\frontmatter{\pagestyle{plain}}
\appto\mainmatter{\pagestyle{main}}
\appto\backmatter{\pagestyle{back}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mainmatter
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\backmatter
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear John. Thank you very much for your support!  The solution works great for the frontmatter and the main part, however, unfortunately not for the backmatter... Here the heading looks rather different, the "chaptername appears left and right for the appendix and bibliography, the page number is at the bottom. I have created a different MWE as a workaround. However, there is still something missing. I cannot apply the second fancypagestyle for the main part. Could you please have a look on it? I will add to the bottom of my first question as an alternative. I should work, I have tested it. BR

Comment: Since every chapter starts with `\thispagestyle{plain}`, there might be problems if you redefine `\chapterhead` in `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.